# Function ends/breaks when calling pool.close(). How can I avoid this or what is the reason?

Tags: python, dataframe, multiprocessing

I started working with `multiprocessing` today and I ran into a problem I do not understand and I cant find an answer for. Here is a minimal example that shows my problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

def parallelizeDataFrameFunction(df: pd.DataFrame, pool, func) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df_split = np.array_split(df, mp.cpu_count())
    return pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split), ignore_index=True)

def normalization(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df["new_col"] = df["old_col"].apply(str_operation)
    return df

def str_operation(mail: str) -> str:
    return s.lower()

print('Do operations with dataframe...')
pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
dataframe = parallelizeDataFrameFunction(
    dataframe, pool, normalization
)
pool.close()
print("...done.")
```

Everything is working fine but when it comes to `pool.close()` the function simply ends. There is no error or anything else, it simply ends. When I do not use `pool.close()` everything workes fine.

Am I missunderstanding anything here?

I am happy with any kind of help,

P

Comment: Did you have a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.close)? *Prevents any more tasks from being submitted to the pool.*. You might also be interested in [join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.join). You also might want to just use `with mp.Pool() as pool:`

Comment: hello @Tomerikoo, thanks for your answer. I read the docs but I did not understand it. When I am using ```with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:``` the function ends as well when this part is done.

Comment: I am not sure what you expect to happen... After the `pool.close()` your script is finished. What indication you have that something is wrong? Did you try adding a `print(dataframe)`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo, thanks for your answer. I thought that only the parallel part ends with ```pool.close()```. Then I will shift it to the very end of my function. Thanks for your answer :-)

Comment: Tag me if you have more issues

Comment: @Tomerikoo: sorry but I need to ask again or better clarity:
Lets assume my example from above. When there is more core after the pool.close() it will never run because the pool.close() ends my programm. What should I do when I waht to free the binded RAM from the parallel processes and want to continue my programm? :-S

Comment: If you think that I should start a new question or reformulate the above one, please let me know

Comment: I think you can just ask a new focused one. But if I understand you, I don't think you need to worry about that. Just use the same pool. My opinion... That's the idea of the pool that it handles everything for you